# “should always have been done”/“should have made”/ should have been always done”

Tags: word-order, syntactic-analysis

So I'm doing a coffeemaker advert in English and it is not my native language. I think you have to know the idea behind this sentence so you can help me to get this grammatically and ideally right.

Concept:

> tasting the coffee which is made by this magnificent coffeemaker and it tastes so good that it feels like the first time you have ever taste coffee. And you think that this is the way coffee should have been always done.

Can you help? How do I say this grammatically correct so also my idea get transmitted to reader?

N.B ***I am not looking for a tagline or slogan***

These are my suggestions:

1. Experience the taste of coffee for the first time as it should always have been done.
2. Experience the first taste of coffee... how it should have made all along.
3. For the first time, experience the taste of coffee like it should have been always done.

Comment: The first time I tasted real coffee I spit it out and vowed never to drink it again.  I kept that vow for 40 years.  2 years ago I tried it again-  and decided I was right the first time.

Comment: You probably want “Experience coffee the way it was meant to be.”

Comment: **For the first time, experience the taste of coffee as it should have been made all along.**  IMHO, you need to emphasize what will change when the customer buys this coffee maker. The introductory phrase sets up the idea that things will be different.

Comment: I understand now that at first this guestion seemed to be about asking opinion but my true intention was to ask how these sentenced are said correctly. Sorry for my bad english. Clobal Charm, I think you are only one who answered the right way. Or is "For the first time, experience the taste of coffee as it should have been made all along" grammatically correct way to say the sentence?

Comment: '... made the way it should always have been' would be more idiomatic. @GlobalCharm's version is a good suggestion too.

Comment: So 'For the first time, Experience the taste of coffee made the way it should always have been' is better/more idiomatic?

Comment: @Jim it was probably French, Greek coffee or if it was me, American filter coffee.... It's like anything in life,  some cooks are better than others, some beers are better tasting than others, etc. so try different types of coffee (Illy/illycaffè) before vowing never to taste something again.

Comment: I've cast my vote to reopen, some users just jump to conclusions without reading the question carefully.

Comment: Personally, my preferred coffee-maker is the DeLonghi Magnifica, which grinds the beans and makes the coffee “espresso style”, from which you can create a variety of coffee drinks. To my mind this would be a tough machine to beat. Good luck with your product.

Answer (score 1):

*"Taste coffee the way it's meant to taste"*, or just

*"Coffee, the way it's meant to taste."*

That would be my stab at coffee. And I'll take a cup for payment, please  >:)

Comment: Doesn't this mean that you  highlight the coffee and it's taste but not the way you make it?

Comment: It tastes that way (the liquid) because of how its prepared (the grinds, etc).

Answer (score 0):

What about
"Return to the origins of coffee and how it was meant to taste."

or "The origin of coffee and its true taste"

or
"The true taste of coffee from its origins"

Several variations around origins and truth or 'returning to its roots' would be good :)

Comment: I think these would work better if i advert coffee itself, but for coffeemaker advert...  I have to emphasize that this coffeemaker will make the difference, not coffee. But thanks for giving me something to think.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how you're fishing for a slogan...

***Coffee - pure and unadulterated***

Comment: I'm not fishing, just wanted to know how these are said correctly. So my client don't get troubles for bad grammar.